# Google Maps v3 Zooming specific location

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i'm still learning the javascript not much pro, and this is my 1st post.

JavaScript

```
function initialize() {

     // Create the map 
     // No need to specify zoom and center as we fit the map further down.
     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
         streetViewControl: false,

     });

     // Create the shared infowindow with two DIV placeholders
     // One for a text string, the other for the StreetView panorama.
     var content = document.createElement("DIV");
     var title = document.createElement("DIV");
     content.appendChild(title);
     var streetview = document.createElement("DIV");
     streetview.style.width = "200px";
     streetview.style.height = "200px";
     content.appendChild(streetview);
     var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
         content: content
     });


     var markers = [{
         lat: 35.15074,
         lng: -89.955992,
         name: "Bob 1"
     }, {
         lat: 35.149425,
         lng: -89.946595,
         name: "Bob 2"
     }, {
         lat: 35.146687,
         lng: -89.929837,
         name: "Bob 3"
     }, {
         lat: 35.132264,
         lng: -89.937197,
         name: "Bob 4"
     }];

     // Create the markers
     for (index in markers) addMarker(markers[index]);

     function addMarker(data) {
         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
             position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng),
             map: map,
             title: data.name
         });

         google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
             openInfoWindow(marker);
         });
     }

     // Zoom and center the map to fit the markers
     // This logic could be conbined with the marker creation.
     // Just keeping it separate for code clarity.
     var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
     for (index in markers) {
         var data = markers[index];
         bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng));
     }
     map.fitBounds(bounds);

     // Handle the DOM ready event to create the StreetView panorama
     // as it can only be created once the DIV inside the infowindow is loaded in the DOM.
     var panorama = null;
     var pin = new google.maps.MVCObject();
     google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(infowindow, "domready", function () {
         panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(streetview, {
             navigationControl: false,
             enableCloseButton: false,
             addressControl: false,
             linksControl: false,
             visible: true
         });
         panorama.bindTo("position", pin);
     });

     // Set the infowindow content and display it on marker click.
     // Use a 'pin' MVCObject as the order of the domready and marker click events is not garanteed.
     function openInfoWindow(marker) {
         title.innerHTML = marker.getTitle();
         pin.set("position", marker.getPosition());
         infowindow.open(map, marker);
     }
 }
```

I had the 4 different places, then i need the 4 webpages to add, how to i tell the browser that i want zooming the specific location. let's say i wanted to zooming at "Bob 1". 
Then i rename the webpage as bob1.html. Whenever i click the bob1.html the webpage will zooming `zoom: 15` and the marker is center on the map

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have four different pages unless this is part of the spec?

To set the position and zoom level of the map simply call:

```
map.setCenter(yourLatLngOrMarkerPosition);
```

And to set the zoom level:

```
map.setZoom(yourZoomLevel);
```

These could be set at any point after the instantiation of the map so perhaps on button clicks or after a period of time?

Hope this helps.

*Edit* To take into account your requirements (mentioned in the comments) I would submit the relevant url post parameters upon clicking the link. Within the initialize function of each map page you will then need to read these out using something similar to [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-url-parameter) (though this uses jQuery) and set the map options as appropriate.

*Edit* You can read the url post parameters out with php and then echo them in the appropriate places within the google maps calls.

For Example:

```
map.setZoom(<?php echo $_GET['urlZoomParam'];?>);
```

Etc.

Some general PHP/MYSQL/Google Maps stack docs: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3 https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3 http://theoryapp.com/online-store-locator-using-php-mysql-and-google-maps/

Comment: what i means is like yelp[dot]com website, whenever click the restaurant, it shows the location.
Thank you for the script, but i'm sure it support if i put on my php

Comment: which is i need more study on URL Parameter. >.<
if there i any solution i can callback from my php file to zoom into specific my 'var markers'

Comment: See edit again. It's quite simple to accomplish in PHP.

Comment: Thank you, will try this script, after cannot find the answer better switch to mysql php google maps. any reference on this. sorry if i'm very annoying. :D

Comment: Edit with some documentation for you.